# Fpdf _construct brings 'unknown page size A4' error?

Tags: php, fpdf

```
class FPDF {
    function FPDF($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $size='A4'){
     }
}
```

changed to

```
class FPDF {
    function _construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $size='A4'){
     }
}
```

because php kept saying using the same name as class is depreciated after I changer unknown page size A4 error displaying. if I change back to the same name it works fine pad generation but sometimes depreciated message displaying.

Comment: Using the class name as the constructor was the OLD way of creating a constructor and is not as the message say `deprecated` (soon to be removed)

Comment: And now it looks like you are trying to create a class called `FPDF` which is the name of the FPDF class, so you will have to use a different name, maybe `my_FPDF`

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to the latest version of FPDF?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here as it might help someone.

I had this class to create the PDF calling a function in the class.

```
class QuotationPdfService extends FPDF
{

    public function viewQuotation(Quotation $quotation) {
        // creating the quotation here
    }
}
```

This was throwing the same error.

> Unknown page size 'a4'

The reason for the error was that even though I am extending the `FPDF` class to my `QuotationPdfService`, I am not invoking the `FPDF`'s constructor function. So a bunch of variables including the `$this->StdPageSizes` which contains the page sizes remain `NULL`. Which is responsible for throwing the error!!

To fix this, you have to call the parent's constructor in the current class `__constructor` function.

```
class QuotationPdfService extends FPDF
{

    public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct($orientation = 'P', $unit = 'mm', $size = 'A4');
    }

    public function viewQuotation(Quotation $quotation) {
        // creating the quotation here
    }
}
```